# Windows Container Load Signing Ceritificate

Tags: windows, iis, containers

I am trying to use a self-signed cert (.pfx) within my windows container (.NET IIS).
I baked the cert under CurrentUser\My and also LocalMachine\My locations but my application still complains saying Certificate with Thumbprint could not be found.

Anyone encountered this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Let your application print out all certificates it can find from those locations and you can then see what the problem is.

Comment: try to place your certificate in your asp.net site rot folder and try to access it. please provide more detail on how you created the certificate and how you are accessing it

Comment: As part of image dockerfile, I am inserting the cert like this:
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; `
    Import-Module IISAdministration; `
    $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $($Env:SENSEISAMLCERT_PWD) -Force -AsPlainText; `
    $cert = Import-PfxCertificate -Exportable -FilePath 'C:\install\saml.pfx' -CertStoreLocation cert:\localMachine\My -Password $pwd; `
    $cert1 = Import-PfxCertificate -Exportable -FilePath 'C:\install\saml.pfx' -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $pwd;

Comment: try to place the certificate file in your site root folder an then try to access that folder certificate with the command.

Comment: after doing this, I now see that its unable to access private key of the certificate. I created my own app pool as part of my dockerfile. what is the best way to assign this app pool permission to read private keys

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the "Allow private key to be exported" when you import the certificate.

you can assign permission to the certificate by following the below ways:

1)if you are running application pool identity then open certificate manager, select your certificate from your location, select all task ->manage private key-> assign IIS AppPool\yourapppoolname and grant it Full control

[image]

2)if you are running an application pool under a custom user account then assign the particular user permission to the certificate as mentioned above.